# What do Toastmasters roles do for hiring?

Tags: resume, human-resources

Is it helpful to include Toastmasters on your resume?  Do HR people care about that?  If so, what should you include? The awards you've achieved? The roles and jobs (e.g., club president) you had?

Do HR people consider Toastmasters roles like area governor or division governor to be leadership experience?

Anything else worth mentioning about Toastmasters from a HR perspective?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace.  I've made some edits to your question to make it less of an "opinion survey" question ("what do you think?" isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange).  I think your core question is whether Toastmasters involvement helps you as a job candidate, so I focused on that.  If I've missed something important please [edit] further.  Thanks.  You might want to check out our short [tour], too.

Comment: what on earth is a Toastmaster?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toastmaster) toastmaster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you apply for leadership roles, then any kind of leadership experience is a plus.

If non-professional leadership experience like Toastmasters or sports clubs are your only leadership experience, you may want to include a sentence or two about how you think that specific experience will apply to the job you apply for.

Personally, I have never heard of Toastmasters, but they have a professional looking website and (at least in my language) a funny name, so it's something to make you stand out from the other CVs in a positive way.

I'd say include it. Maybe HR will find it positive, I cannot think of an instance where they'd see it negative. There's little risk and a potential gain.

Comment: +1 Anything that offers evidence of applicable skills and/or experience should be included in a resume. For example, I use my time as a Scouting commissioner (essentially a leader of adult leaders) to show organisational and leadership skills. But, if there are no direct skills, don't bother (I was also in various other volunteer organisation, like St John's Ambulance).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Toastmaster, and I think it's a plus on a resume.  Don't make big deal about it though, the person looking at the resume will either know what Toastmasters are , or they won't.

Comment: Additionally, I recommend using a few key words. Like "Advanced Communicator and Advanced Leadership Awards including serving as Area Governor". Even if HR doesn't care, it is a potential discussion point at the interview.

Answer (score -3):

Unless the job requires it, or the position would benefit from not being afraid to make a speech, I don't see how it helps.

HR won't care. They only look at the key words on the resume to see if you pass the first hurdle. They also reject those that far exceed the requirements for the job. If the job requires 5 years of X and you have 7, great. If you can play 12 musical instruments they won't care.

The people focused on picking the right candidate won't care about the extras listed on the resume, unless it directly applies. If you include outside activities and somebody making the decision likes that activity or appreciate that activity it can help them remember you. Otherwise it is neutral at best.

If during the interview they ask you for an example where you took the initiative on your own to improve your performance in the workplace: and you talk about how you felt your ability to talk in front of groups was poor, so you joined Toastmasters and now you are much better. That would help. But Toastmasters doesn't have to be on the resume, CV or cover letter to talk about it.

Comment: many companies look for well-rounded staff, not just one-trick ponies. I've never met the company that would disqualify someone for being well-rounded, so there is upshot to including it, and no downside.

Comment: It is hard to think of a professional career that you can go far without being able to give competent presentations. I used to suck at them in every possible way. I joined Toastmasters. I wouldn't say I am now good at giving presentations but I am certainly at least competent thanks in large part to my joining ToastMasters. I still usually don't "feel" like I gave a good presentation, but people usually come up to me and say I gave a good presentation, so that is something. Anyways, if there's an appropriate place to put it then most certainly do. It shows you have bigger aspirations to some.

Comment: -1 For neutral at best.  Taking leadership roles in social organizations at the regional level shows initiative and marginally valuable leadership experience.  Most likely a very slight positive.